# Sort and omit NAs in multiple columns of different length

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting

I have a data frame with 563 columns.

Each column currently has rows of different length and NAs

For example:

```
col_1     col_2   col_3   ...   col_563  
"1"       "3"     "1"           NA
"3"       "4"     "3"           "2"
"2"       "1"     NA            "3"
NA        "2"     NA            "1" 
"4"       NA      "2"           NA
```

I want to sort all columns and omit the NAs so it looks like this:

```
col_1     col_2   col_3   ...   col_563  
"1"       "1"     "1"           "1"
"2"       "2"     "2"           "2"
"3"       "3"     "3"           "3"
"4"       "4"
```

To first sort the columns, I tried:

```
df_sorted <-df_final[order(df_final[,1:563] ),]
```

But the program crashed. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You cannot have columns of different lengths in a data.frame. So what should be the empty cells? Empty characters ""`?

Comment: @denis
yes, that will be the desired result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
your_df[] <- lapply(your_df, sort, na.last = TRUE)
your_df[is.na(your_df)] <- ''
```

> ```
>   col_1 col_2 col_3 col_563
> 1     1     1     1       1
> 2     2     2     2       2
> 3     3     3     3       3
> 4     4     4              
> 5
> ```

Answer (score 3):

```r
df[] <- apply(df, 2, sort, na.last = TRUE)

#   col_1 col_2 col_3 col_4
# 1     1     1     1     1
# 2     2     2     2     2
# 3     3     3     3     3
# 4     4     4    NA    NA
# 5    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

###### Data

```r
df <- data.frame(
  col_1 = c(1, 3, 2, NA, 4),
  col_2 = c(3, 4, 1, 2, NA),
  col_3 = c(1, 3, NA, NA, 2),
  col_4 = c(NA, 2, 3, 1, NA)
)
```

Comment: Do note that this converts to a matrix. (+1)